# Is it possible to insert data in a the second array when the first one is full?

Tags: java, arrays, exception, if-statement, while-loop

I am practicing Java and working on arrays. As arrays size can not be changed in run time, is it possible to make 2 arrays and in run time keep storing input in the first of and then when it is full, then move to the second array by if statement.  I'm basic in Java so hope my code is in the right direction. Anyway it does not work but I just want to share my idea and see if it can work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] arr1 = new int[5];
    int[] arr2 = new int[10];

    while(in.hasNextInt())
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <= arr2.length; i++)
        {
            if (i <= arr1.length) { arr1[i] = in.nextInt(); }
            else arr2[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Arrays are allocated at run time, but they are fixed size once they are allocated. Have you tried to use an ArrayList instead? It manages this stuff for you

Comment: Run the code and see if it works.  Worth 10,000 answers here.

Comment: @mehsook Well I know ArrayList works but I'm wondering if this idea works by Arrays.

Comment: @duffymo I bet you didnt read the last sentence of my post. ;)

Comment: That's even worse - you know it doesn't work.  Why write "see if it can work"?  Bad question, bad code, bad....

Answer (score 1):

You should change your code to the following:

```
if (i < arr1.length) { arr1[i] = in.nextInt(); } //"<" instead of "<="
else { arr2[i - arr1.length] = in.nextInt(); } //decrement i by the size of the first Array
```

As denoted in the other answer/answers, there are plenty of more practical ways to do what you are trying to achieve, but non the less the above should let your code work as inteded.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good idea. If the second array overfills, you'll have problems such as exceptions and lost data.

I recommend using the `ArrayList`.

You can create one:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<>();
```

and add to it with:

```
list.add(new Integer(in.nextInt()));
```

With autoboxing you can skip the creation of an integer reference object and use:

```
list.add(in.nextInt());
```

Answer (score 0):

> Anyway it does not work ...

Yea.  Pretty obviously.

> ... but I just want to share my idea and see if it can work.

No.  Pretty obviously.

Sure you can put elements in the second array when the first array.  But then you run into the same problem all over again when when the second array fills up.

---

The best solution is to use an `ArrayList<Integer>` (... or any kind of `List<Integer>`).  That will take care of the problem of "growing" the list transparently and automatically.

If you *insist* on doing this with arrays, then the solution is to:

1. dynamically allocate a "new" array that is bigger than the "current" array,
2. copy the elements of the "current" array to the "new" array, and
3. assign the reference for the "new" array to the "current" array variable.

In fact, you could do all of this using [`Arrays.copyOf(int[], int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29).